# How do you make json $ref to local files?

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I am using the [AJV](https://ajv.js.org/) package in my node.js project.

I am trying to validate some data against a couple of schema files. Both of these schema files are in the same directory:

```
/dir
    |
    parent_schema.json
    |
    sub_schema.json
/data
    |
    data.json
```

I am trying to get a super simple example of the `$ref` property working but I am having trouble. `parent_schema.json` looks like:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string" },
    "bar": { "$ref": "sub_schema.json" }
  }
}
```

And `sub_schema.json` looks like:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "sub1": { "type": "string" },
  }
}
```

And I am trying to validate my `data.json` which for the sake of completeness looks like:

```
{
  "foo": "whatever",
  "bar": {
    "sub1": "sometext"
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with my `$ref` path. I am getting this error from AJV:

```
MissingRefError {
    message: "can't resolve reference subschema1.json from id #"
    missingRef: "subschema1.json"
    missingSchema: "subschema1.json"
}
```

Anyone see what's wrong with my path? I know you are also supposed to use the `#` to select what specific property you want matched against, but I want the ENTIRE schema to be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a common misconception that `$ref` somehow "loads" a file.

See what [ajv.js.org](https://ajv.js.org/#ref) says:

> $ref is resolved as the uri-reference using schema $id as the base URI (see the example).

And:

> You don’t have to host your schema files at the URIs that you use as schema $id. These URIs are only used to identify the schemas, and according to JSON Schema specification validators should not expect to be able to download the schemas from these URIs.

Ajv won't try loading this schema from `stack://over.flow/string` for example:

```
{
  "$id": "stack://over.flow/string",
  "type": "string"
}
```

If you want to reference that schema in another schema, they both need to have the same base URI `stack://over.flow/` e.g.,

```
{
  "$id":  "stack://over.flow/object",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": { "$ref": "string#" }
  }
}
```

Here `{ "$ref": "string#" }` says *"import the schema at stack://over.flow/string"* so you end up with:

```
{
  "$id":  "stack://over.flow/object",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "$id": "stack://over.flow/string",
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

This allows you to combine small schemas:

```js
const ajv = new Ajv;

ajv.addSchema({
  "$id": "stack://over.flow/string",
  "type": "string"
});

ajv.addSchema({
  "$id": "stack://over.flow/number",
  "type": "number"
});

const is_string = ajv.getSchema("stack://over.flow/string");
const is_number = ajv.getSchema("stack://over.flow/number");

console.log(is_string('aaa'), is_string(42));
console.log(is_number('aaa'), is_number(42));

const is_ab = ajv.compile({
  "$id":  "stack://over.flow/object",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": { "$ref": "string#" },
    "b": { "$ref": "number#" }
  }
});

console.log(is_ab({a: "aaa", b: 42}));
console.log(is_ab({a: 42, b: "aaa"}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.12.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

---

*(Please note that in your example both schemas are incorrect. You're missing `{"type": "object"}` in both.)*

To answer your question:

```js
const ajv = new Ajv;

ajv.addSchema({
  "$id": "stack://over.flow/parent.schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string" },
    "bar": { "$ref": "child.schema#" }
  }
});

ajv.addSchema({
  "$id": "stack://over.flow/child.schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "sub1": { "type": "string" },
  }
});

const is_parent = ajv.getSchema("stack://over.flow/parent.schema");
const is_child = ajv.getSchema("stack://over.flow/child.schema");

console.log(is_parent({
  "foo": "whatever",
  "bar": {
    "sub1": "sometext"
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.12.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Technically the OP’s given examples are valid even without the `type` keyword. That just allows non-objects (e.g. `null`, `string`, `number`) to be valid against those schemas (which may or may not be desirable). For the non-objects the `properties` keyword would simply be ignored. That being said, I believe some validators act as you describe and enforce a `type` being specified, i.e. it’s probably a good practice to include it unless one really wants to allow non-object values.

Comment: @Carsten That's true; they're still valid even without the `type` keyword. I just assumed it was an oversight from OP as while valid technically they would also be "useless" unless they're `$ref`'ed into other schemas. Good comment!

Comment: I did not realize how important IDs were for getting $ref to work, thank you.

Comment: **"If you want to reference that schema in another schema, they both need to have the same base URI"** --- The base URI can also be the empty string.