# Reference the same json object across multiple schema

Tags: javascript, json, git, jsonschema

I have a git folder containing multiple json schema used to validate objects, taking the form:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": { "type": "number" },
        "property2": { "type": "number" },
        "property3": { "type": "string" },
        "sharedProperty": { "enum": [ "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5" ] }
      },
      "required": [
        "property1",
        "property2",
        "property3",
        "sharedProperty"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ]
}
```

I want to make `sharedProperty` common across the x number of schema in the folder, such that whenever an update to the property is required, it only needs to be done once in one central place. Something along the lines of:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "property1": { "type": "number" },
        "property2": { "type": "number" },
        "property3": { "type": "string" },
        "sharedProperty": { "$ref": "/schema/sharedProperty.json" }
      },
      "required": [
        "property1",
        "property2",
        "property3",
        "sharedProperty"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "data"
  ]
}
```

Is referencing an external file inside a json possible? Does it require any additional code in the index.js file to facilitate calling the shared property from inside the schema? There's then the additional question of how to combine referencing another file with `enum` in the schema itself.

Comment: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62348626/1244884